# Cells with multiple text lines in w2ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, w2ui

I would like to have several text lines in one cell in w2ui grid. I tried the following code:

```
$(function () {
            $('#grid').w2grid({
                name: 'grid',
                header: 'List of Names',
                columns: [
                    { field: 'fname', caption: 'First Name', size: '30%' },
                    { field: 'lname', caption: 'Last Name', size: '30%' },
                    { field: 'email', caption: 'Email', size: '40%' },
                    { field: 'sdate', caption: 'Start Date', size: '120px' }
                ],
                records: [
                    { recid: 1, fname: "Peter", lname: "Jeremia", email: 'peter@mail.com <br> peter@ypeter_corporation.com', sdate: '2/1/2010' },
                    { recid: 2, fname: "Bruce", lname: "Wilkerson", email: 'bruce@mail.com', sdate: '6/1/2010' },
                    { recid: 3, fname: "John", lname: "McAlister", email: 'john@mail.com', sdate: '1/16/2010' },
                    { recid: 4, fname: "Ravi", lname: "Zacharies", email: 'ravi@mail.com', sdate: '3/13/2007' },
                    { recid: 5, fname: "William", lname: "Dembski", email: 'will@mail.com', sdate: '9/30/2011' },
                    { recid: 6, fname: "David", lname: "Peterson", email: 'david@mail.com', sdate: '4/5/2010' }
                ]
            });
        });
```

I received a grig where all rows have same height. The one cell, which have two lines of text, was looked ugly:
[image]

So my question is: Is there a simple way to make row height adjustable to number of text lines?

Answer (score 2):

As of now (w2ui 1.4 and w2ui 1.5 RC1) there is no way to have dynamically sized rows.
You can however set the height for **all** rows using `grid.recordHeight`

From the [docs](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2grid.recordHeight):

> Records are of fixed height. If you want to create grid with multiple lines per record, you need to change this property.

There's also a good reason for this: by default only the visible cells are rendered and all scrolling (both horizontal and vertical) is virtual. To know how many records are displayed and to calculate the height of the scrollbar (and to know when to display the scrollbar) the grid must be able to easily calculate the height of the rendered rows - that's why all rows have the same height.

Comment: Is there a merged cells feature in w2ui? Kind of one in Handsontable

Comment: @A.Bykov No. In w2ui cells can not have a colspan or rowspan.